# How can I view all of my answers that are quoted elsewhere in someone else's answer?

Tags: support, answers, data-explorer, linked-questions

Recently I saw an answer from another user where they had quoted one of my answers within theirs. It felt nice.

So that had me wondering, is there any way to see all my answers that are quoted elsewhere by some other users?

I know I can go through all my answers and see the linked posts which may or may not show me the desired results but that is kind of hectic. What I am looking for is a list. I think SEDE's might be the only way, if any. This was originally posted on Sci fi SE meta but It has been pointed out to me that I would get better responses here.

I am trying something like this:

```
SELECT Id AS [Post Link] FROM Posts 
WHERE PostTypeId = 2 
AND OwnerUserId != ##UserId## 
AND Body LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT Id FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 2 AND OwnerUserId = ##UserId##),'%')
```

But of course this one doesn't work because the subquery is returning more than one values (As it should, given that I want to evaluate the body against all of my own answers) and my knowledge of SQL leaves much to be desired so can't evaluate the body against the Post Ids of all my answers.

Comment: Could you link and example please?

Comment: @JakeSymons Sure, [Like this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/178223/54887)

Comment: Originally posted on [SFF meta here.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11644/58193)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this I used some arguably pretty narrow definitions for what counts as a quote. I assumed that a quote is, at very least, a link back to the original post. This link has to have the following format: `scifi.stackexchange.com/a/<postid>`. The query then takes all posts that contain such links, checks whether they link back to one of your posts, at reports that.

The results are the original post, the quoting post, and whether or not you self-quoted in that specific instance or not.

The tally seems to be:

- 10 quotes by others
- 24 quotes by yourself

[**The Query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/779744/posts-by-aegon-quoted-with-url)

Comment: This does not account for multiple quotes in one post. I'm looking for a way to mitigate that

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be possible to use the `string_split` function on SEDE, which exhausts my ideas to improve on this.

Comment: Just leave out that distinction by self-quote and it works fine.